# Git executable for IntelliJ on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, git, github, intellij-idea

I'm running Windows 8 and for proper IntelliJ 12.0.3 configuration I need to give IDE information where it's able to localise the GitHub executable.

Since I'm new to the Windows 8 platform, I tired to use a few searches to localise it. Did anyone encountered this problem as well?

Using different IDE is not an option at the moment :/.

Thanks for hep in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install [msysgit](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list) and specify its path in IDEA settings:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe
```

See also [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11497637/104891) if you want to use `git.exe` provided by GitHub application.